# Denodo on RHEL 7 without gui

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, rhel, denodo

How to install Denodo on rhel7 CLI without GUI?

i have installed it using denodo_installer_cli.sh on rhel7 and it was successful.

1. it is throwing an error x11 variable not found. while i run the script denodo_platform.sh.
2. all the requirments has been fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that you are encountering an X11 variable not found error when running the denodo_platform.sh script after successfully installing Denodo on RHEL 7 using the denodo_installer_cli.sh script.

For a headless installation, as you don't have a GUI, you can run the installer in text mode or silent mode.

You can refer to the Denodo Community document on Headless Installation for instructions on text mode or silent mode installation: [Denodo Headless Installation](https://community.denodo.com/kb/en/view/document/Headless%20installation), that talks about "unset DISPLAY" command.

Hope this helps.